# Weird css difference between chrome and IEE

Tags: css, joomla, padding, styling

I am doing a website in the joomla16 framework, using a modified beez5 template. I am getting a strange result from IE. Chrome shows the site as it is intended, however IEE is adding a padding I can't seem to find anywhere. I've been using IE dev tool vs. the Chrome element inspector to find this discrepancy, but it's nowhere to be found.

The site is http://85.233.235.109/joomla16/

Any help or suggestions would be gladly appreciated.

Edit:

I am testing with IE 8.0.(7601)

UPDATE:

I seem to have found something in the IE dev tool. 
Using the layout pane you can get the calculated sizes of the different elements.

The div id="header-image" has a size of 1050x137, 
whereas the a class="logo" and the img class="logo" both have a size of 1050x134.

This would account for the 3 pixel line, but I don't see where it is generated.

Comment: internet explorer is commonly called "IE", not "IEE". Also, what version(s) of IE have you been testing with?

Comment: It seems I have found the solution, although it's a strange one.

By setting height of div id="header-image" to a fixed 134px (
header-image{height:134px;})

the problem is solved, and the results are the same in IE and Chrome. However, I don't know why IE is adding a 4 pixel difference in the element, when the absolute height is not entered.

Comment: well done for finding a solution. Sounds like you may just have to write this one off as "one of those weird IE quirks". There's plenty of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I have found the solution, although it's a strange one.

By setting height of div id="header-image" to a fixed 134px ( header-image{height:134px;}) the problem is solved, and the results are the same in IE and Chrome.

However, I don't know why IE is adding a 4 pixel difference in the element, when the absolute height is not entered.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess: IE might run your site in quirks mode, where it emulates the behaviour of IE6. To disable quirks mode, you have to specify a correct doc type. The correct doctype for HTML5 is for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Comment: the linked page does have a doctype, so it shouldn't be in quirks mode.

Comment: Doctype is specified as <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">